# jQuery is not calling .done() when the ajax call is successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

We're building a node.js application using Express, but are separating our layers. So the browser is running pure jQuery and javascript, the web server and application server are Node.js and Express. We're using REST APIs between them all.

We're using jQuery 1.10.2

Since the application server cannot be open to the public, the browser must make API calls to the web server, which manages making the call to the application server and returning the results. Here is what that looks like...

```
// Proxy all other API calls to the backend server
var request = require('request');
app.all('/api/*', function (req, res) {
    var targeturl = apihost+req.originalUrl;
    console.log("Proxy: "+targeturl);

    request({
        url: targeturl,
        method: req.method,
        json: req.body
    }, function (error, response, data) {
        if(error) {
            res.send(error);
            res.end();
        } else {
            console.log("SUCCESS...");
            console.log(data);
            res.send(data);
            res.end();
        }
    });
```

});

Our data is a two-level hierarchy of Flows and one or more child Milestones on each Flow. When someone clicks the Save link on our page to save a Flow and its Milestones, the Javascript pulls the Flow data from the page, then makes an AJAX call to save the Flow information first, then waits for the "done()" handler before pulling the Milestone information from the page and making a second AJAX call to save that data. Here is the saveFlow() function executed in the browser...

```
function saveFlow(organization_id, user_id, flow_id) {
    var name = $('#Name').val();
    var purpose = $('#Purpose').val();
    console.log("Trying to save flow: " + flow_id);

    if (name && name.length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
                url: "/api/flow",
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'json',
                data: {
                    flow_id: flow_id,
                    name: name,
                    purpose: purpose,
                    organization_id: organization_id,
                    user_id: user_id,
                    timestamp: (new Date())
                }
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                console.log("Could not save the flow: " + error.message);
            })
            .done(function (flow) {
                console.log("Saving milestones for flow "+flow.id+" ["+flow_id+"]");
                saveMilestones(flow.id);
            });
    } else {
        console.log("Refusing to save a flow that has no name");
    }
}
```

The proxy code shows me that this call succeeded...

```
SUCCESS...
{ success: true,
  message: 'Flow Updated!',
  id: '56de8e346d229b492a0954f9' }
```

But the proxy code also demonstrates that the next API call never takes place. Moreover, the log statement in the Done block is never executed, nor are any log statements placed inside the saveMilestones() function.

Clearly, the .done() handler is never being called in this case. I use the done() handler in other parts of my code and it works. I've compared the code but don't see any differences. The proxy code we're using is driving every other API call made from our pages successfully, so I don't think that it's failing to return the success status.

I've done a lot of searching on this site and tried every suggestion I could find - adding a explicit "json" datatype parameter, switching from ":success" to ".done()" - but nothing has worked yet. I even tried switching from done() to always() - a bad idea but I wanted to see if it would get called...and it wasn't called.

It's also worth noting that the .fail() handler is also not being executed.

Is it possible that the JSON block we're sending back to indicate success is somehow failing to make jQuery realize that we were successful? Or is it possible that the AJAX call is crashing when it tries to process the successful return? If so, how do I catch that to prove it and fix it?

Hope someone can help.

Comment: If neither the `fail` or `done` callbacks are executed, the ajax call never happens.

Comment: Working with a friend of mine on this, we've determined that the proxying code might be at fault. Essentially, it's an Ajax call within another Ajax call. Since they are both asynchronous, the outer call (made from the browser to the web app) is terminating before the inner call (from the web app to the app server) has time to send back its results. We found this from the Network panel in Chrome's debugger - the call is listed as "cancelled".

Comment: So the real question is...how can I sync the outer and inner calls so that the outer one waits for the inner one to finish?

Comment: After working on this with a friend of mine, we realized that the proxy code works for almost every other part of the application. It's only when we are daisy chaining two Ajax calls together in the browser using the "done()" handler that we seem to have a problem. Can anyone explain that? Is there a reason why that might be the case?